# How to cover spaces ending in line <p> tag

Tags: html, css

My paragraph not well formated , there is diffrent whites space in end of each line.

```css
p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>An area of the site that we feel will be a great revenue stream is advertising from
companies related to the market or interested in the profile of people we will be
attracting.
We would want this to be maximised to get the best return for both parties without
making the site look too commercial. </p>
```

I want to remove all spaces in end of each line.

Comment: text-align: justify should work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do some changes like:

```
p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```css
p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<p>An area of the site that we feel will be a great revenue stream is advertising from
companies related to the market or interested in the profile of people we will be
attracting.
We would want this to be maximised to get the best return for both parties without
making the site look too commercial. </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try **text-align: justify;** css property:

```css
p {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>An area of the site that we feel will be a great revenue stream is advertising from
companies related to the market or interested in the profile of people we will be
attracting.
We would want this to be maximised to get the best return for both parties without
making the site look too commercial. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
```